# trigger to update contact lastname field with lastname+count

Tags: before-trigger

Can we further optimise this trigger to count related contacts on account and update the contact last name field  with lastname+count, whenever new contact is inserted?

```
trigger contactinsert on Contact (before insert) {
    list <id>acclist = new list<id>();
    for (contact con :trigger.new){
        acclist.add(con.accountid);
    }
  
    for (account a :[select id,(select id from contacts) from account where Id IN :acclist]){
        for (contact cont:trigger.new){
            if(cont.accountid == a.id){
                integer count=a.contacts.size();
                count++;
                cont.LastName=cont.LastName+count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Premature optimization is evil. Before you start thinking about optimizing, you need to figure out 2 things:

1. What specific thing do I want to improve (cpu time used, queries used, number of records able to be processed, etc...)?
2. How can I measure that thing I want to improve?

In this case though, I don't think you're looking to optimize. Instead, this is an issue of removing an anti-pattern (i.e. a particular way of doing something in code that people have identified as bad practice) from your code.

The following general pattern is a red flag

```
for(object 1){
    for(object 2){
        if(object1.field == object2.field){
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

The number of times the inner loop runs quickly grows with the number of object1 and object2 records.

- If object1 has 10 records and object2 has 20 records, your inner loop executes n*m times (10 * 20 = 200)
- If object1 has 20 records and object2 has 100 records, your inner loop executes 2000 times

Instead, you should build a Map where the key is the field you're trying to compare the two objects against

```
Map<Id, Object1> obj1Map = new Map<Id, Object1>();

for(Object 1){
    obj1Map.put(object1.Id, object1);
}

for(Object 2){
    Object1 = obj1Map.get(object2.field);

    // The 'continue' keyword tells us to skip the rest of the loop
    //   and start working on the next item
    // I find this approach (keeping the main logic out of as many IFs as possible)
    //   to generally be easier to read/understand
    if(object1 == null){ 
        continue;
    }

    // do work
}
```

- If object1 has 10 records and object2 has 20 records, you loop a total of n + m times (10 + 20 = 30)
- If object1 has 20 records and object2 has 100 records, you loop a total of 120 times

Answer (score -1):

```
trigger contactinsert on Contact (before insert) {
    
    list <id>acclist=new list<id>();
    for (contact con:trigger.new){
        acclist.add(con.accountid);
    }
    
    
    map<id,account>mapAccId=new map<id,account>([select id,(select id from contacts) 
                                                 from account
                                                 where id in:acclist]);
    
    
    for (contact cont:trigger.new){
        account rec=mapAccId.get(cont.AccountId);
        integer count=rec.contacts.size();
        count++;
        cont.LastName=cont.LastName+count;}
    
}
```